# How to copy only the last record in a DataTable to another DataTable

Tags: c#

How to copy only the last record in a DataTable to another DataTable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, unless I'm missing something, you can just [`ImportRow` it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308909):

```
newDataTable.ImportRow(firstDataTable.Rows[firstDataTable.Rows.Count - 1]);
```

Comment: i think that's what you want aparnakarthik

Comment: thanks a lot
Similarly is it possible to copy only the first record in a DataTable to another??? pls help :-) thanx

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
    public DataTable CopyLastRowToNewTable(DataTable dt)
    {

        DataTable dtNew = dt.Clone();

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
               dtNew.ImportRow(dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]);
        }

        return dtNew;

    }
```

To copy the first row you would use this:

```
dtNew.ImportRow(dt.Rows[dt.Rows[0]);
```

instead of

```
dtNew.ImportRow(dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]);
```

Comment: is it possible to copy only the first record in a DataTable to another??? pls help :-) thanx

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt;
DataTable dt2;

DataRow dr = dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1];
dt2.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Or directly

```
dt2.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]);
```

Comment: is it possible to copy only the first record in a DataTable to another??? pls help :-) thanx

Comment: Yes! It would almost be the same :) 

dt2.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[0]); 

is what you are looking for. It is 0 because arrays are 0 based :)